# Xcode 5.0.1 iOS 7.0.3 Instruments dev tool is blocked when a script capture is launched

Tags: xcode-instruments

Since i upgraded to Xcode 5.0.1  Instruments dev tool is blocked when a script capture is launched.
The same workflow is working when choosing an iso6.1 simulator.

Here are some details:
My Config:
Xcode 5.0.1
Simulator configuration: iOS7.0
SDK version: 7.0
Application deployment target : 7.0

Workflow:

1- in Xcode create a new iOS project  .
2- Make sure that target is iOS7, iPhone simulator .
3-  Launch the product in Instruments (Click Product ->Profile choose Automation and click  Profile)
4- Click stop.
5- In Script panel click Add-> Create. 
6- At the bottom of the window Click Record (Button with red dot)

Result : Instruments dev tool is blocked with message "Starting capture"  and spinner.

```
 The same workflow is working when choosing an iso6.1 simulator.
```

I've done re-installing XCode  and still get the same problem.

Anyone else have this issue?
Who can help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Have the same Issue.Could not find adequate solutions ,but you can use Instruments 5.0(Xcode 5.0) and everything will work.